# What to call this latex material used to tie trees?

Tags: tree-care, terminology

I got some special hollow (rope/wire/string/tube - I don't know how to call it) - it is green and made of latex about 4 or 5 mm in diameter and used to tie young trees to prevent wind damage.

Can anyone tell me what this is called and maybe where I can buy some more of it?

Or alternatively what other good materials can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Your question will get more attention and better answers if you can supplies photos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This looks](http://www.pghorticulture.co.uk/level2/tytube.html) like what you're talking about. If that's the right stuff, it is called "tying tube", "tree tying tube" or "binding tube".